# Want to connecting to https host with PHP soap client

Tags: php, soap, ssl, https

I wrote a php library which call to a wsdl in http.

Now i want to do the same things via https/ssl protocol.

So i changed the wsdl path but is not sufficient.

Here the code:

```
    <?php
    $options = array(
                            'trace' => 1,
                            'exceptions' => 0,
                            'login'         => $login,
                            'password'      => $password
    );
    $wsdl= "https://toto.com/tata/ws/tutu?wsdl";

    $service = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options); 
    ?>
```

In the server, i received the hit correctly but over http, not https:

For your information, i have openssl enabled:

```
openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

Have you an explaination about that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL file does contain the URLs to use for a service call. Is this changed to HTTPS as well? If not, you'd only see the request for the WSDL using HTTPS (and PHP has a cache for it, so it won't occur every time if not disabled).

Comment: Ohh yes!
The wsdl in http and https are the same, they display a schemaLocation to a http link and not https.

Thanks!
Do you know if i can modify the wsdl in https only in order to set the https address?

Comment: I have changed the url in the wsdl, so the hit for the wsdl is now in https but the next hits to the action of the webservices are in http :(.